# How to make multiple items drag and drop using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable

By referring to the drag and drop feature on this page
http://skfox.com/jqExamples/SortableSelectable.html, I have done a script which works exactly like the example. But my problem is, I want to allow my users to easily drag and drop multiple items at once. How can I do this, by editing the example script?

To allow multiple drag and drop, I can think of two ways:

1. Ctrl+select multiple items in the first list, then drag and drop to the 2nd list
2. Add check boxes to the first list. Users will check the checkboxes, and click on a button "Add" - which will add all those checked items to the 2nd list.

Comment: Something like this could get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/slamborne/eGR6t/ (ctrl + click selects the lis)

Answer (score -1):

Does this solves your problem?

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

I don't think this supports multiple drags at the same time, but you could do something like this: whenever an element is ctrl-clicked, is added to a global array and then when you drag the last one of them, all the elements of that list are appended to an invisible div which is draggable.
That way, you simulate multiple dragging.

Comment: Thanks, but not really... I already have drag and drop. But, now, I want to add the ability to drag and drop multiple items.

Comment: Thanks. I am rather new to jQuery... although I kind of understand your logic, but I have no clue how to code it. A quite and more detailed guide will be nice... better still some real code. Sorry, if I have asked too much.

Comment: No you're not asking too much. Im kind of bussy right now that's why I did not write it, but if no one writes my idea before, I'll do it soon. Please wait.